# Conditional formatting of Google SpreadSheet's cell based on proximity to upcoming date not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

A picture is worth thousand words

[image]

So, why isn't the first date cell yellow? It's in the selected range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did not use valid formula...

**`=TODAY()`**
**`=TODAY()+30`**

[image]

Comment: The equal sign was the key. Thanks!